# d3 embeded image displayed twice

Tags: javascript, image, d3.js, embed

I'm embedding an image on a d3 diagram as in this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/707681f1f5b4a2063d6e):

```
  var logoCanvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas")
    .attr("id", "newCanvas")
    .attr("width", width / 2)
    .attr("height", height / 2)
    .node();

  var context = logoCanvas.getContext("2d");
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.src = 'myImage.svg';
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
    var imageData = document.getElementById("newCanvas").toDataURL("image/png")
    //Add as SVG image element
    d3.select("svg").
    append("image")
      .datum(imageData)
      .attr("height", 100)
      .attr("width", 100)
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + [offsetX - 50, offsetY - 50] + ')')
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
        return d
      })
  }
```

This works all as expected but unfortunately I get the image displayed twice. Basically I only need the appended one and not the one which is drawn onto the context. The thing is the I can't get the appended one without drawing it first.

Is there a way to hide the Image which is drawn in context?

Or a smarter approach of only getting one image displayed but embedded?

Comment: Can you try fetching the base64 code of the image by reading the image using [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) ? If you aren't sure how to do that, please add a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with the image, I'll help you out.

Comment: You won't be needing a canvas at all, if you have the base64 code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [code](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2104/p9o7mjap/) snippet of an `XMLHTTPRequest()` and `FileReader()` approach to fetch a image and "embed" into a SVG. You don't need a canvas at all.

```js
// append svg
d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("height", "300px").attr("width", "276px");

var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr1.open('GET', 'https://s7.postimg.org/40f9flc1n/dummy1.png');
xhr1.responseType = 'blob';
xhr1.onload = function () {
  var fs = new FileReader();
  fs.onload = function (result) {
    d3.select("svg").append("image")
      .datum(result.target.result)
      .attr("height", 300)
      .attr("width", 276)
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
        return d
      })
  };
  fs.readAsDataURL(xhr1.response);
};
xhr1.send();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.7/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps. :)